# Можно ли сказать "экспонировалась выставка"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли сказать "экспонировалась выставка"?
Вроде бы экспонирование и есть выставление.
Хотя в Нацкорпусе есть ОДИН такой пример (или там тоже могут быть ляпы?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, так говорить не следует. Экспонировать- выставлять." Выставлять выставку," - звучит нелепо. А вот "экспонировать на выставке" можно, так же как и "выставлять экспонаты".  В данных словооборотах используемые синонимы исключают повторение и помогают точно передать смысл.